# installing django 1.5(development version) in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to start developing a web apps using django 1.5 but I can't figure out how to install the django 1.5 in the `virtualenv` because django 1.5 is still a development version.

I've tried installing it using `easy_install` and `pip` but all I get is django 1.4 because it is the official version.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: my answer is actually the answer that will stand the test of time :P

Comment: @SkylarSaveland answer should definitely be the winning one!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Directly from the github repository.

```
pip install git+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.5b2
```

Comment: I can install django 1.5 using git. But I don't understand why I got several syntax error in main.py, loader.py, case.py, suite.py. Can you please tell me why I get those syntax error.<br>
Thank you

Comment: changing mode of build/scripts-3.2/django-admin.py from 664 to 775
      python3.2/site-packages/django/utils/unittest/main.py", line 153
        except getopt.error, msg:
                           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
      unittest/loader.py", line 92
        except Exception, e:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
      unittest/case.py", line 327
        except SkipTest, e:
                       ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
      suite.py", line 141
       except Exception, e:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Because I'm still a new member here I can't give an answer for my own question that's why I can only show you the error using comment.

Comment: >>> django.VERSION
(1, 6, 0, 'alpha', 0)

Comment: Then add the relevant tag
pip install git+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.5b2

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to pip install django, is there a way to install it correctly, without all those syntax errors? At the end, it says "Successfully installed Django Cleaning up...". I don't understand.

Comment: I still prefer @skylar-saveland answer that gives you more control on what you get: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13960686/422670 But for a stable deployment that you don't want to change often this can be ok.

Answer (score 42):

[Django 1.5 was released!](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/feb/26/15/).  To install it use:

```
pip install django
```

To install the latest development version without git, on your own risk use:

```
pip install https://github.com/django/django/zipball/master
```

<strike>[Django 1.5 Release Candidate 2 (RC2) was released](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/feb/19/security/), and it can be installed using pip without installing git:</strike>

```
pip install https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.5c2/tarball/
```

Comment: I still prefer @skylar-saveland answer that gives you more control on what you get: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13960686/422670 But for a stable deployment that you don't want to change often this can be ok.

Comment: @Stefano You will still need git to use the other way.

Comment: yes indeed you need to have git installed on your system, though I don't see that as an issue!

Answer (score 11):

Now that the github version is 1.6 'alpha' (atm), to get the 1.5.x branch, you can:

```
pip install --upgrade git+http://github.com/django/django.git@stable/1.5.x#egg=django
```

Edit: You may need to `pip uninstall Django` to remove previous versions.

Comment: I like this the most because you get the LATEST 1.5, not bound to a specific beta or candidate. Easier to upgrade.

Comment: I'm doing this now, with Django 1.4.3 currently installed, but pip says "Requirement already up-to-date". I can't work out how to force it to upgrade to 1.5.x.

Comment: FWIW, I had to uninstall Django 1.4.3 before doing the above to get 1.5.x.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is instruction](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) how you can grab the code from git. After that go to your virtual env

```
source ~/path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

and go to downloaded sources and run setup.py:

```
python setup.py install
```

and now you have installed latest development Django.

Comment: Or as VMitov said, there is qiucker way to install it directly by pip.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link could be useful: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Option 1.

You can install the latest official version of Django:

```
pip install Django==1.6.3
```

Option 2.

You can try out the beta:

```
pip install https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.7b2/tarball/
```

Option 3.

You can get the latest development version:

```
git clone https://github.com/django/django.git
```