# How can I install Django version 1.5?

Tags: django, installation

If I do `pip install django` I get version 1.4.  If I do `pip install Django==1.5` I get the message `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==1.5 (from versions: )`.  If I install the latest version from github I get version 1.6 alpha.

Comment: Almost an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339608/installing-django-1-5development-version-in-virtualenv - though here not-virtualenv answers are accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django 1.5 is still in alpha.  You can download a tarball from the [download page](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) or you can `git clone` the github repository and switch to what I think is the 1.5 branch with `git checkout stable/1.5.x`.  I'm not sure why 1.5.x is considered a "stable" branch when it's in alpha, but that's the only branch that obviously qualifies.

Either way, I recommend you do the actual installing with `pip install -e (directory name)` if you can.

Comment: Also, will I then be able to update the repository I have downloaded and only get updates that belong to the 1.5 branch?

Comment: Yes.  Assuming you don't `git checkout` another branch, then only the 1.5 updates will appear in your source tree (git will also be downloading the other updates, but it will store them separately so they won't affect your active installation).

Answer (score 5):

Directly from github repository:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.5b2
```

Comment: What does this do? Will it get me version 1.5 or 1.6?

Comment: It will give you the latest development release, which when I just tried it is 1.6.

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13960686/422670 is a better way to get the latest 1.5.x